# DataGrid scrolling causes mixed values

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid, scroll

When I got a list binded in a `DataGrid` (WPF or Silverlight), the values in this `DataGrid` are mixing when I scroll up and down.

[image: Scrolling behavior]

On the left original values and on the right the values after scrolling.

Here some Xam (nothing special):

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding LookupTable1}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Path=TextValue}"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color" Width="*">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadColorPicker/>
                </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you expect people to divine where in the code you didn't post the error can be found?

Comment: Might be a case of attached properties on the `DataGridRow` combined with a virtualizing `DataGrid` but it's hard (read impossible) to tell without any code

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you've bound the telerik colorpicker to any property on your itemssource, so I don't see how it would know what color to show for any individual row.  I'm not particularly familiar with the telerik controls per se but do they show a random color if not initialized when instantiated?

```
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color" Width="*">
         <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                      <telerik:RadColorPicker/> <!-- this isn't bound to anything //-->
              </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
         </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```